# Не переведено сообщение во время проверки своего вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если во время создания вопроса допустить одну ошибку, то пишет:

> [image]

А если 2 или 3 ошибки, то пишет:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Что-то ещё осталось не переведено из упомянутого?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ нет, все переведено

Comment: Я в таких случаях ставлю тревогу "требуется внимание модератора с комментарием, что можно вешать красную метку [статус-завершено]". Я уже флагнул, так что сейчас не надо, инфа на будущее, так сказать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил переводы для:

few  - https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13625
many - https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13626

Ожидается в свежих сборках. Текущая rev 2020.10.13.37803